# trying to fix my bug

Tags: javascript, jquery

im making a slide text from right to left , but when goes on left side stop moving and start again ...i want it to never stop moving from right to left .. here is     my code ..

```
function change_left() {
$('#slide12').removeClass('slide-right').addClass('slide-left');
}

function change_right() {
$('#slide12').removeClass('slide-left').addClass('slide-right');

}

function to_left() {
setInterval(change_left, 5000);

};

function to_right() {
setInterval(change_right, 5000);
};
to_left();
to_right()
```

Comment: you want it to go back right again after it reaches left?

Comment: no , to stop moving till the sentence end and then to disappear in right

Comment: Whats the question?

Answer (score 2):

You can use css. no need jquery.

```css
body { margin: 20px; }

.marquee {
  height: 25px;
  width: 420px;

  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.marquee div {
  display: block;
  width: 200%;
  height: 30px;

  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;

  animation: marquee 5s linear infinite;
}

.marquee span {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

@keyframes marquee {
  0% { left: 0; }
  100% { left: -100%; }
}
```

```html
<div class="marquee">
  <div>
    <span>You spin me right round, baby. Like a record, baby.</span>
    <span>You spin me right round, baby. Like a record, baby.</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Man you are awasome

Comment: @hry Thanks man. Don't forget to mark as answer.

Comment: Where can i mark as a answer ?

Comment: left side to this answer after votes there is tick mark click on that

Comment: in starting of my answer . left side -> after < 2 > arrows

Comment: marking means accepting answer

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using css.

**HTML**

```
<div class="display">
<div class="moving-text">
Moving...
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.display{
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  background:#000000;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.display .moving-text{
  display:inline-block;
  font-size:40px;
  padding:25px;
  color:green;
  position:absolute;
  -webkit-animation: leftright 5s infinite; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  animation: leftright 5s infinite;
}

@keyframes leftright {
    0%   {left: 0;}
    100% {left: 100%;}
}

@keyframes rightleft {
    0%   {left: 100%;}
    100% {left: 0;}
}

@keyframes both {
    0%   {left: 0;}
    49%   {left: 100%;}
    100% {left: 0;}
}
```

You can change animation: ***leftright*** 5s infinite; with 'rightleft' or 'both'

This is JsFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nuwanniroshana/xzwnsm3q/)